# scrapy: how to scape both <ul> and <li> one by one?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, response

Using Python scrapy to get content from webpages, I want to get things in the following order:

Living room, Chair's link

Living room, Sofa's link

...

Bed room, Bed's link

Bed room, Mirror's link

...

By now, urls are correct, but all `sub_cat` printed out in `parse_item_info` are `Living room`. When I try to print out `sub_cat` in `parse_item`, I got all subcategories.

I think the problem is that the tags `<li>` in `<ul>` are gotten twice. How can I get them right one by one? 
Thanks.

html:

```
  <div class="row margin-b2">
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="font-size-3 color-yellow main-list-li">
                                    Living room
                                </li>
                                <ul class="list-inline main-list-ul">   
                                    <li class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top">
                                            <a href="https://www.website.com/furiture/536" class="text-light">Chair</a>
                                    </li>
                                    ...
                                </ul>   
                                <ul class="list-inline main-list-ul">   
                                    <li class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top">
                                            <a href="https://www.website.com/furiture/537" class="text-light">Sofa</a>
                                    </li>
                                    ...
                                </ul>


                                <li class="font-size-3 color-yellow main-list-li">
                                    Bed room
                                </li>

                                <ul class="list-inline main-list-ul">   
                                    <li class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top">
                                            <a href="https://www.website.com/furiture/538" class="text-light">Bed</a>
                                    </li>
                                    ...
                                </ul>   

                                <ul class="list-inline main-list-ul">   
                                    <li class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top">
                                            <a href="https://www.website.com/furiture/539" class="text-light">Mirror</a>
                                    </li>
                                    ...
                                </ul>       

                                ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       </ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Python:

```
   def parse_item(self, response):
        cat = response.meta["cat"]
        out_box = response.xpath('//div[@class="row margin-b2"]')

        # get all sub categories first
        sub_cat_arr = []
        for box in out_box.xpath('//li[@class="font-size-3 color-yellow main-list-li"]'):
            sub_cat = box.xpath('./text()').extract()[0].strip()
            sub_cat_arr.append(sub_cat)

        i = 0
        for box in out_box.xpath('//ul[@class="list-inline main-list-ul"]'):
            sub_cat = sub_cat_arr[i]
            i += 1
            print("in......")
            print(sub_cat)
            for url_box in box.xpath('//li[@class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top"]//a'):
                new_url = url_box.xpath('.//@href').extract()[0]
                yield scrapy.Request(new_url, meta={"url": new_url, "cat": cat, "sub_cat": sub_cat}, callback=self.parse_item_info)


    def parse_item_info(self, response):
        cat = response.meta["cat"]
        sub_cat = response.meta["sub_cat"]
        url = response.meta["url"]
        print(sub_cat)
        print(url)
        ...
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output using your sample html?

Comment: @JackFleeting Finally found the bug. I missed a dot before `//li[@class="list-inline-item main-list-li-w align-text-top"]//a`. Thanks.

Comment: @JackFleeting But I don't know if it's the best way, I wanted to use one loop to get the data, but now I have to use two loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not process same tags twice You definitely need to use only one cycle:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
    cat = response.meta["cat"]
    for tag in response.css("ul.list-unstyled li.font-size-3.color-yellow.main-list-li, ul.list-inline.main-list-ul li a"):
        if tag.root.tag == "li":
            current_sub_cat = tag.css("*::text").extract_first("").strip("\n ")
        elif tag.root.tag == "a":
            new_url = tag.css("*::attr(href)").extract_first()
            sub_cat = current_sub_cat
            yield scrapy.Request(url=new_url, meta={"new_url": new_url, "sub_cat": sub_cat, "cat": cat}, callback=self.parse_item_info)
```

Comment: Well, this is what I want. Thanks.